# Почему при использовании функции locateonscreen из pyautogui происходит завершение работы скрипта? И как поправить чтобы все заработало?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('21.png'):
    print("OK")
else:
    print("NON")
```

Скрипт ищет на экране определенное изображение, если изображение существует выводится сообщение "OK" иначе "NON". Ранее все работало, но пришлось переустановить OS X и скрипт перестал работать! Выдает следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py",     line 234, in _locateAll_python
raise StopIteration()
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/userNama/Documents/Python/aps_v_2/test.py", line 3, in 
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('21.png'):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py",    line 266, in locateOnScreen
retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py",   line 250, in locate
points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
[Finished in 14.5s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u',   '/Users/userName/Documents/Python/aps_v_2/test.py']]
[dir: /Users/userNama/Documents/Python/aps_v_2]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Что ему нужно я не понимаю. Помогите пожалуйста добрые люди)

Comment: Попробуйте установить opencv-python. Похоже проблема в _locateAll_python. Если будет установлеy opencv, то для поиска на экране будет использоваться его метод. Я не уверен, но похоже еще можно ваш код обернуть в try/except и поймать StopIteration, что будет тот же `print("NON")`. Сама бага вот тут проявляется: https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L234

Comment: Счастья тебе gil9red!!! После установки opencv3 все заработало! И все же до переустановки OSx работало без opencv, где я что не так сделал, где ошибка...?

Comment: Возможно, opencv уже стоял. Хорошо, что у вас получилось, я тогда ответ подготовлю. Жаль что вы вариант с try/except не проверили

Comment: Думаю, что вариант с try/except стопроцентный. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автору помогла установка [opencv-python](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

---

Модуль [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) использует функцию `locateOnScreen` из модуля [pyscreeze](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze), поэтому там нужно искать проблему и [она была в функции _locateAll_python](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L234), которая при определенном условии будет вызываться как [locateAll](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L453).

Само условие вызова:

```
...
if useOpenCV:
    locateAll = _locateAll_opencv
    if not RUNNING_PYTHON_2 and cv2.__version__ < '3':
        locateAll = _locateAll_python
else:
    locateAll = _locateAll_python
```

Я предположил что той баги нет в реализации на `opencv` и не ошибся.

---

Могу предложить вариант без установки `opencv`, получится так:

```
import pyautogui

found = None

try:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('21.png'):
        found = "OK"
    else:
        found = "NON"

except StopIteration:
    found = "NON"

print(found)
```